# Javascript - Buttons select and unselect

Tags: javascript, select, button

I have some buttons below in my HTML:

```
<p>
<input class="answerBtns" name="answer" type="button" value="A" />
<input class="answerBtns" name="answer" type="button" value="B" />
<input class="answerBtns" name="answer" type="button" value="C" />
<input class="answerBtns" name="answer" type="button" value="D" />
<input class="answerBtns" name="answer" type="button" value="E" />
</p>
```

What I want to know if lets say I want the user to select 3 buttons for example, then if the user clicks on a button, it will highlight the button in a color (lets say green) but the user can only have three buttons selected. If an additional button is clicked then that button would not be selected. The additional button can only be selected if the user unselects a selected button and then selects the button he wishes. This means that only 3 buttons can be selected at maximum.

My question is that what functions in Javacsript can be used to be able to do this?

Thank You

Comment: This is possible with plain JS, but it will be much easier with jQuery. -- Take a look at the functions `addClass`, `removeClass`, `hasClass` and on the general selectors `$('.my_class')` -- http://api.jquery.com/

Comment: The `name` should be unique for each button.

Comment: in the Javascript I am calling it answer[0], answer[1], answer[2], etc so it saves me typeing in getElementsbyName for each name if each name was unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you have to give your buttons different names.

```
<input class="answerBtns" id="answer1" type="button" value="A" onclick="changeClass(this.id);" /> 
<input class="answerBtns" id="answer2" type="button" value="B" onclick="changeClass(this.id);"/> 
<input class="answerBtns" id="answer3" type="button" value="C" onclick="changeClass(this.id);"/> 
<input class="answerBtns" id="answer4" type="button" value="D" onclick="changeClass(this.id);"/> 
<input class="answerBtns" id="answer5" type="button" value="E" onclick="changeClass(this.id);"/>
```

What I would suggest is using jquery to change the class of the button to something like answerBtnsSelected when a button is selected this, will also help you with your css styles to highlight the button.

What you can then do is create a function that checks the amount of buttons with that class, and if it's three or more then ignore or whatever, else change the class to make it selected.

**Added logic to unselect button**

```
function changeClass(id)
{
    if ($('#' + id).hasClass('answerBtnsSelected'))
        $('#' + id).removeClass('answerBtnsSelected');
    else
    {
        if ($('.answerBtnsSelected').length < 3)
        {
            $('#' + id).addClass('answerBtnsSelected');
        }
        else
        {
             alert('Only three buttons can be selected.');
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok I will try this and see how it goes. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<style  type="text/css">
.answerBtnsOff
{
    BACKGROUND-COLOR: #ffffff;
    BORDER-BOTTOM: #666666 1px solid;
    BORDER-LEFT: #666666 1px solid;
    BORDER-RIGHT: #666666 1px solid;
    BORDER-TOP: #666666 1px solid;  
    COLOR: #c;
    FONT: 11px Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.answerBtnsOn
{
    BACKGROUND-COLOR: GREEN;
    BORDER-BOTTOM: #666666 1px solid;
    BORDER-LEFT: #666666 1px solid;
    BORDER-RIGHT: #666666 1px solid;
    BORDER-TOP: #666666 1px solid;  
    COLOR: #ffffff;
    FONT: 11px Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
}
</style>
<script lang=javascript>
var currenttotal=0;
function getButtons()
{
    document.getElementById("answerA").class="answerBtnsOff";
    document.getElementById("answerA").setAttribute("class","answerBtnsOff");
    document.getElementById("answerA").setAttribute("className","answerBtnsOff");
    document.getElementById("answerB").class="answerBtnsOff";
    document.getElementById("answerB").setAttribute("class","answerBtnsOff");
    document.getElementById("answerB").setAttribute("className","answerBtnsOff");
    document.getElementById("answerC").class="answerBtnsOff";
    document.getElementById("answerC").setAttribute("class","answerBtnsOff");
    document.getElementById("answerC").setAttribute("className","answerBtnsOff");
    document.getElementById("answerD").class="answerBtnsOff";
    document.getElementById("answerD").setAttribute("class","answerBtnsOff");
    document.getElementById("answerD").setAttribute("className","answerBtnsOff");
    document.getElementById("answerE").class="answerBtnsOff";
    document.getElementById("answerE").setAttribute("class","answerBtnsOff");
    document.getElementById("answerE").setAttribute("className","answerBtnsOff");

    currenttotal=0;
}
function btnclick(btn)
{
    if(document.getElementById("numberDropId").value=="")
    {
        alert('Select option');
        return false;
    }
    if (btn.class=="answerBtnsOn")
    {
        btn.class="answerBtnsOff";
        btn.setAttribute("class","answerBtnsOff");
        btn.setAttribute("className","answerBtnsOff");
        currenttotal--;
        return false;
    }
    if(document.getElementById("numberDropId").value==currenttotal)
    {
        alert('Not allowed beyond limit, deselect other button');
        return false;
    }
    if (btn.class=="answerBtnsOff")
    {
        btn.class="answerBtnsOn";
        btn.setAttribute("class","answerBtnsOn");
        btn.setAttribute("className","answerBtnsOn");
        currenttotal++;
        return false;
    }

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>
    <select name="numberDropId" id="numberDropId" onchange="getButtons()" >
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
    </p>
    <p>
    <input class="answerBtnsOff" name="answerA" id="answerA" type="button" value="A"  onclick='javascript:btnclick(this);' />
    <input class="answerBtnsOff" name="answerB" id="answerB"  type="button" value="B"  onclick='javascript:btnclick(this);'  />
    <input class="answerBtnsOff" name="answerC" id="answerC"  type="button" value="C"   onclick='javascript:btnclick(this);' />
    <input class="answerBtnsOff" name="answerD" id="answerD"  type="button" value="D"   onclick='javascript:btnclick(this);' />
    <input class="answerBtnsOff" name="answerE" id="answerE"  type="button" value="E"   onclick='javascript:btnclick(this);' />
    </p>
    </body>
    </html>
```